# Is $L^\infty(0,T;V)$ a reflexive space? Question about weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $V$ an Hilbert space and $T>0$. Is $L^\infty(0,T;V):=\{v:[0,T]\to V: \text{ess}\,\text{sup}_{t\in [0,T]}||u(t)||<\infty$ a reflexive space?

I think that since the $L^\infty$  isn't reflexive, then $L^\infty(0,T;V)$ couldn't be reflexive too.

I'd like that any bounded sequence in $L^\infty(0,T;V)$ converges weakly, but since this space is not reflexive, i can' get this.

Am I right? Thanks for your help

Comment: Not every bounded sequence converges weakly in reflexive spaces also...

Comment: of course, I can take a weakly convergent subsequence in $L^\infty(0,T;V)$ from any bounded sequence? how i can prove ( or disprove) it?

Comment: yes, i have a mistake in the comment above, i'll edit

Comment: No. Reflexivity is equivalent to weak compactness of the closed unit ball. Eberlein tells us this in turn is equivalent to weak sequential compactness.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help =)

Comment: However, (if $V$ is separable) you can extract a subsequence $\{u_n\}$, such that $\int_0^T (u_n(t), v(t))_V \, \mathrm{d}t$ converges for all $v \in L^1(0,T;V)$.

Answer (score 3):

Any closed subspace of reflexive space is reflexive. $L_\infty[0,T]$ is not reflexive but embedded in $L_\infty([0,T],V)$ as closed subspace via the map $i(f)(t)=f(t)x$, where $x$ any norm one vector in $V$.

Comment: i don't understand,... $L^\infty(0,T;V)$ is still non reflexive?

Comment: yes$\phantom{}$